# css stop image moving on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, zurb-foundation

I have the following layout: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/test/aldemair-productions/.

When I scroll up if the mouse is on the image it looks like the image scrolls too, it almost seems like the red box is fixed but it is not.

There seems to be 2 scroll bars at some point.

What I would except to happen is this: https://jsfiddle.net/7n554u1t/4/.

I have tried to use this:

```
.img{

background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

but that creates a parallax effect and I don't want that.

Comment: Well you can just add `overflow-x: auto` to `.off-canvas-wrapper`

Comment: I took a look at your html on that page - on your header element you have added 'position: fixed;' to it. You said "it almost seems like the red box is fixed but it is not", so I'm not sure if this styling is intentional or not. Try removing that if you did not mean to 'make it fixed. If you need more assistance please include a sample of the html/css you currently have along with a picture or explanation of what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating your css at **app.css** (`line no - 2569`) from :

```
.off-canvas-wrapper {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

To

```
.off-canvas-wrapper {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Removing  `overflow-x: hidden;` .

Comment: that would work but overflow-x: hidden is used for when opening the off canvas foundation menu

Comment: @Alex :  Okay ,I will check more , will update my and if I get somthing

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction, I ended up adding/removing overflow-x: hidden with js.